# Do all polynomials (other than generalized cyclotomic polynomials) have the spaced polynomial property?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Anna Erschler just asked me a question that is posed as Question 1.2 in her recent preprint with J. Frisch and M. Rychnovsky. I am asking it here with her permission - since I find it interesting (apparently it also has strong implications) yet I am less able to help her directly than plenty of people here are likely to be. (I also told her to talk with the Lehmer/Mahler tribe and, more generally, with Diophantine folk; that was off-the-cuff - please correct me if that was not the most accurate advice.)

---

Let $P\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dotsc,x_k]$ be a non-zero irreducible polynomial. Assume $P$ is not of the form $Q(M)$ for any generalized cyclotomic polynomial $Q$ and any monomial $M$. Must $P$ satisfy the spaced polynomial property?

---

(Erschler-Frisch-Rychnovsky say that a polynomial $P(x_1,\dotsc x_k)$ satisfies the *spaced polynomial property* if there is some positive integer $N$ such that, for every polynomial $Q$ with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$, $P$ does not divide $Q(x_1^N,\dotsc,x_k^N)$. For them, a polynomial is *generalized cyclotomic* if it is an irreducible polynomial dividing the difference $M_1-M_2$ of two distict monomials $M_1$, $M_2$.)

Comment: I do not understand the definition. If $N=1$ does not work, that is, $P$ divides a polynomial with coefficients $0,\pm 1$, then so does $P(x_1^N,\ldots,x_k^N)$ for every $N$, no?

Comment: Sorry, messed up the question - corrected!

Comment: $P$ is a polynomial with coefficient in which field (or ring)?

Comment: Still do not understand. $x-y$ divides $x^N-y^N$, but it is not of the form $Q(M) $

Comment: @YCor Coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @FedorPetrov My bad again; corrected.